# What is happening here in Python with OOPs while trying Diamond Shape problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I am learning OOPs with python. created below code to replicate the diamond shape problem in multiple inheritence. I am running the below code in jupyter notebook and output is generated at same.

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=2
        self.b=4
    def form1(self): 
        print("calling parent from1")
        print('p',self.a+self.b)

class child1(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=50
        self.b=4
    def form1(self):
        print('bye',self.a-self.b)
    def callchildform1(self):
        print("calling parent from child1")
        super().form1()

class child2(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=3
        self.b=4
    def form1(self):
        print('hi',self.a*self.b)
    def callchildform1(self):
        print("calling parent from child2")
        super().form1()

class grandchild(child1,child2):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=10
        self.b=4
    def callingparent(self):
        super().form1()

g=grandchild()
g.form1()
g.callchildform1()
g.callingparent()
```

The output is below

```
bye 6
calling parent from child1
hi 40
bye 6
```

I can understand the "bye 6" output both the times but how it is printing "hi 40". I am new so anybody can explain what is happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find the `__mro__` attribute of a class informative. Here, MRO stands for **M**ethod **R**esolution **O**rder.

Consider this modification to your code:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2
        self.b = 4

    def print_name(self):
        print("parent")

    def form1(self):
        print("calling parent form1")
        print('p', self.a + self.b)


class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 50
        self.b = 4

    def print_name(self):
        print("child1")

    def print_super_name(self):
        super().print_name()

    def form1(self):
        print('bye', self.a - self.b)

    def callchildform1(self):
        print("calling parent from child1")
        super().form1()


class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = 4

    def print_name(self):
        print("child2")

    def form1(self):
        print('hi', self.a * self.b)

    def callchildform1(self):
        print("calling parent from child2")
        super().form1()


class Grandchild(Child1, Child2):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 4

    def print_name(self):
        print("grandchild")

    def print_super_name(self):
        super().print_name()

    def print_super_super_name(self):
        super().print_super_name()

    def callingparent(self):
        super().form1()


g = Grandchild()
print("When I print the name of my class it is:")
g.print_name()
print("When I print my superclass name, it is:")
g.print_super_name()
print("When I print the name of the superclass of my superclass, it is:")
g.print_super_super_name()
print("When you call methods on me, they will be executed from my class and my parent classes in the following order:")
print(Grandchild.__mro__)
g.form1()
g.callchildform1()
g.callingparent()
```

The output is:

```
When I print the name of my class it is:
grandchild
When I print my superclass name, it is:
child1
When I print the name of the superclass of my superclass, it is:
child2
When you call methods on me, they will be executed from my class and my parent classes in the following order:
(<class '__main__.Grandchild'>, <class '__main__.Child1'>, <class '__main__.Child2'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class 'object'>)
bye 6
calling parent from child1
hi 40
bye 6
```

When you run `g.callchildform1()` Python looks for the definition of `callchildform1` in `Grandchild`. It isn't there, so the next place it looks is `Child1`. You can see from the example and from the method resolution order that when an instance of `Grandchild` calls a method defined in `Child1` which calls `super()`, the search for the called method will begin in `Child2`.

Comment: ohhh okay. thank you for the help. It makes a lot of sense now. wow.