# What is the Diamond Problem in Python and why its not appear in python2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, diamond-problem

I got this code:

```
class A:
 pass

class B(A):
 pass

class C(A):
 pass

class D(A,B):
 pass

d = D()
```

In Python3 i get a MRO Error. I mean it appears because the Diamond Problem. In Python2 its no Problem. Why is this the case, and what is this Diamond Problem exactly ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is happening here in Python with OOPs while trying Diamond Shape problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615536/what-is-happening-here-in-python-with-oops-while-trying-diamond-shape-problem)

Comment: because python 3 is better than 2! :P You can actually click the tag you used to read up on diamond problem.

Comment: In Python 2, `A` is an old-style class, and there is no (formal) concept of an MRO for such classes. The C3 linearization algorithm, which is what produces the MRO error, is not applied.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is *not* the diamond problem!

The diamond problem occurs when two classes have a common ancestor, and another class has both those classes as base classes, for example:

```
class A:
    def do_thing(self):
        print('From A')

class B(A):
    def do_thing(self):
        print('From B')

class C(A):
    def do_thing(self):
        print('From C')

class D(B, C):
    pass

d = D()
d.do_thing()
```

In some languages, because of how inheritance is implemented, when you call `d.do_thing()`, it is *ambiguous* whether you actually want the overridden `do_thing` from `B`, or the one from `C`.

Python doesn't have this problem because of the *method resolution order*. Briefly, when you inherit from multiple classes, if their method names conflict, the first one named takes precedence. Since we have specified `D(B, C)`, `B.do_thing` is called before `C.do_thing`.

That is also why you get that problem. Consider this: since `B` inherits from `A` in your example, `B`'s methods will come before `A`'s. Say we have another class, `B_derived`, that inherits from `B`. The method resolution order will then be as follows:

```
B_derived -> B -> A
```

Now, we have `D` in the place of `B_derived`, therefore we can substitute it in to get this:

```
D -> B -> A
```

However, note that you have also specified that `D` inherits from `A` before `B`, and by the rule above, `A` must also come before `B` in the method resolution order. That means we get an inconsistent chain:

```
D -> A -> B -> A
```

*This*, and not the diamond problem, is why you get an error.

(See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217501/question-related-to-super-with-init/56217632#56217632)).

Comment: But why is it a problem? We search from left to right. IF we are looking for the `do_thing` method, then we start from `A`, move to `B` if we don't find it in `A`, move again to `A` and stop. What is the inconsistent in this chain?

Answer (score 0):

Diamond problem is a problem in multiple or hybrid inheritance.
It is a relationship exist when at least one of the parent classes can be accessed through multiple path from the bottommost class.
The bottommost class inherits the members of the base class via different path so that it creates ambiguity or create duplicate members.
The method resolution order(MRO) tells python how to search for inherited methods.
This comes in case of multiple or hybrid inheritance when using super() because the MRO tells you exactly ehere the Python will look for method you are calling with super() and in what order.
Every class has an .**mro** attribute that allows us to inspect the order.

```
class vehicle(object):
     def __init__(self,name):
         print(name,"is vehicle")
class fly(vehicle):
     def __init__(self,canfly):
         print(canfly,"can fly")
         super().__init__(canfly)
class run(vehicle):
     def __init__(self,canrun):
         print(canrun,"can run")
         super().__init__(canrun)
class both(run,fly):
     def __init__(self,name):
         super().__init__(name)
vehicle=both("mig")
both.__mro__
```

Comment: You didn't answere why it does not occur on Python2

Comment: This answers the question what the problem is, what happens, and how python deals with it. There is no reason to be mean. I came here for this and found out the answer was given downgraded. That is a shame. The issue with python two is a specific case that can be addressed here further.